# Ratio of Certain Dependent Random Variables

Tags: statistics

**Disclaimer**: This problem is for my own understanding and not for a class in any way.

Greetings!

I am trying to solve the following problem but I am unsure how to proceed beyond what I have below. The trouble I am having is that $Z$ and $W$ and not independent of one another and so I am not sure how to address this dependency.

I have solved for $Z$ using the standard approaches for hierarchical distributions and so I should be good up to that point.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Let $w < v$. We wish to solve

\begin{align}
    W \overset{iid}{\sim} U(0,w)\\
    Z \sim U(W,v)
\end{align}

solving for $Z$, we obtain

\begin{equation}
    Z \sim - \ln z I_{(0,z)}(z)
\end{equation}

and so

\begin{equation}
    \frac{Z}{W} \sim ???
\end{equation}

Comment: It might improve readability to define $W$ first (rather than $Z$ first),  since $Z$ seems to be defined in terms of $W$.  Actually, before all of that it would help to say $v$ is a fixed positive real number. And what does "iid" mean in this context?

Comment: @Michael - Thank you for that input. "iid" means "independent and identically distributed". Indeed v is a fixed and non-zero value.

Comment: Yes,  "iid" is standard for "independent and identically distributed." But for this context, what is independent of what? Why did you put "iid" over $\sim$?  You have only two random variables $Z$ and $W$, and it looks to me like $Z$ and $W$ are _not_ independent, nor are they identically distributed.  I also think there is some error in your PDF for $Z$.  It should be a function of $z$ for example.

Comment: @Michael - Ok I think I made all the changes you suggested. Take a look.

Comment: Sure you want to look at the case $v<w$?  If $v=w$, the idea of the proof is exactly the same but the computations are less annoying...

Comment: Hmmm... and the PDF you suggest for $Z$ is absurd.

Comment: You can solve by conditioning on all values of $W$.  So $$ f_Z(z) = \int_{t=0}^w f_{Z|W}(z|t)f_W(t)dt =\int_{t=0}^w f_{Z|W}(z|t)\frac{1}{w}dt $$ and computing this gives an answer for $f_Z(z)$ in terms of $v,w, z$.  Also $$P[Z/W \leq u] = \int_{t=0}^w P[Z/W \leq u | W=t]\frac{1}{w}dt $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment:** To me, this is still not clearly stated. (In particular, I don't follow your last two displayed formulas.) Here is a speculative interpretation
of a special case. First, you select $W \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0, 5).$ Then
you select $Z \sim \mathsf{Unif}(W, 10).$ So $Z$ has support $(0,10),$
but is hardly independent of $W$. Thus, the distribution of $Z$ is a 'mixture'
of uniforms with random left boundaries determined by $W.$

[A simplification would be to let $Z$ be a 50:50 mixture of $\mathsf{Unif}(2,10)$ and
$\mathsf{Unif}(4,10)$.]

A quick simulation (in R) of what I describe is shown below. If this is the right
interpretation, seeing a histogram of a million simulated $Z$'s might help you solve
the problem. (The 'ramp' at the left is not linear.) If not, maybe you can try once more to explain what you want.

```
set.seed(429);  m = 10^6;  a = 5;  b = 10;  z = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  w = runif(1, 0, a);  z[i] = runif(1, w, b) }
summary(z);  sd(z)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 0.006075  4.558774  6.387860  6.245682  8.191052 10.000000 
[1] 2.320161

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
abline(v=c(a,b), col="red", lwd=3, lty="dashed")
```

[image]

A scatterplot of the first 20,000 $(W,Z)$ pairs (captured by a sligtly
different program) is shown below. Notice the higher density toward the right.

[image]